# Swift, How can I share API result in all over my app?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I need to request to some API, to get: user data, user following, user follower. They are 3 different APIs. I need to call them every 1 minute. I put this part of code in my app *delegate* and I don't have any problem with it. but I need to refresh the `ViewController` the user is already in it, whenever new information got from server. I need something like *RXSwift* to subscribe for new data and update the view whenever new data is available. But I don't know how to do it.because my API call is in app *delegate* and user can be in any `ViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know RX Swift, but what you describe is a classic [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) use case.
I would `post` a notification using the `NotificationCenter` and subscribe to it in my view controllers.
[KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) is another way to go, but I would go with notifications, given the scenario you described.

Example:

```
// This class does the API stuff
class MyClass{

    static let myNotification = Notification.Name("com.mycompany.intersting-notification")

    func apiCall(){
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyClass.myNotification, object: "Hello!")

    }
}

// in your view controller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: MyClass.myNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        if let str = notification.object as? String {
            print("Somebody sent us this: \(str)!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) like below. Also you can use [Delegates](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) ,  Here is a good blog regarding NotificationCenter [Blog](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/using-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift-eb70cf0b60fc). Hope it will help.

```
// In viewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
  selector:#selector(GetApiDetails), name: 
  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "GetApiDetails"), object: nil)
}
 // In viewWillDisappear

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "GetApiDetails"), object: nil)
}

// Get/Use your related api result in this function
@objc   func GetApiDetails(notification: NSNotification){
// do your stuff here
}

// Now Call UserNotification Center method in your appdelegate file in a method and pass the values if you want to in your object like array or dictionary or according to your convenience.
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "GetApiDetails"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to inform **N** instances about the API response, then you can use `NotificationCenter` or `KVO` and if you need is only to access the API result throught the application, then you may use **Singleton**(if the data is temporarily required) or **Persistence Storage**(if the data is to be stored permanently) such as `NSUserDefaults`, `SQLite` or `CoreData`

Example by @Moshe Gottlieb

```
    // API Class
    class MyClass{ 

            static let myNotification = Notification.Name("com.mycompany.intersting-notification")

            // API Call
            func apiCall(){ 

                // on API completion, post(publish or send) a notification using the syntax
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyClass.myNotification, object: "Hello!")

            }
        }

        // UIViewController / Any class  initial load method
        override func viewDidLoad() { 
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // register or observe or listen for notification of name
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: MyClass.myNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in

                // closure called when notification is received
                if let str = notification.object as? String { // data fetched from notification
                    print("Somebody sent us this: \(str)!")
                }
            }
        }
```